# Execution failed for task ':bintrayUpload'.

Tags: android, maven, jcenter

I want to upload  my library to jecenter.
I have created bintray account etc & followed all steps which are mentioned here.

I did below changes in my application module & library module.

//Library build.gradle

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    resourcePrefix "winchance"

    version = "1.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName version
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}

def siteUrl = "https://github.com/lubeast/WinchanceHttpUtil"
def gitUrl = "https://github.com/lubeast/WinchanceHttpUtil.git"

group = "com.winchance.library"

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        // This generates POM.xml with proper paramters
        pom {
            project {
                packaging 'aar'

                name 'Net Utils for Winchance'
                url siteUrl

                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                        url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'lumeng'
                        name 'lumeng'
                        email 'jiahehz@gmail.com'
                    }
                }

                scm {
                    connection gitUrl
                    developerConnection gitUrl
                    url siteUrl
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())


bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
    key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")

    configurations = ['archives']

    pkg {
        repo = "maven"
        name = "winchance-http-util"
        websiteUrl = siteUrl
        vcsUrl = gitUrl
        licenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
        publish = true
    }
}
```

//Top-level build.gradle

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**When i excuted gradlew bintrayUpload** it shows

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':library:bintrayUpload'.

  > Could not create package 'LuMeng/maven/WinchanceHttpUtil': HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [message:This resource requires authentication]

Please help me, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing same problem. For some reason, it is not able to get bintray.user & key from the properties file. Try to hardcode the user and key and then try again.